# Two separate WPF forms, same RichTextBox object?

Tags: c#, wpf, thread-safety

I have two WPF forms and they represent two different views of my data. They both have rich text boxes which represent status bars and they both have "Save" buttons to export the data into csv/xls when needed.

I am also using threading to access my rich text boxes at runtime and update their text value with appropriate message, like "File saved".

However, the app behaves as if I have only one rich text box object in memory, meaning, when I press "Save" button in Form1, it automatically updates the rich text box in Form2.

I found I can use this context class:

```
SynchronizationContext context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
fsw = new FileSystemWatcher();
fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
fsw.Path = Constants.EXPORT_PATH;

// Add event handlers.
fsw.Changed += (s, e) =>
{
    context.Post(val => statusBarSiteProduktiPoSIRTB.Text = "The data was saved to " + fileName, s);
}; 

fsw.Created += (s, e) =>
{
    context.Post(val => statusBarSiteProduktiPoSIRTB.Text = "Saving data to " + fileName + ", please wait!", s);
};

// Begin watching.
fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

statusBarSiteProduktiPoSIRTB is the name of the RichTextBox in Form1 and statusBarSiteSISoRokoviRTB is the name of the RichTextBox  in Form2

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong? 
Why it looks like there is only one rich text box object in memory?

Comment: So where is the Code you are accessing `statusBarSiteSISoRokoviRTB `?

Comment: @RandRandom the event handlers with lambda notation. Button click event. Why does it matter?

Comment: You are saying that your second RichTextBox gets updated, but we can only see the code where you work with the first RichTextBox - so, we cannot really tell what is going wrong when we only see one side - your described behaviour is impossible with the code you have shown so far - you are only accessing the one RichTextBox - but if you insist on the fact that this code alone makes trouble give this line of code a try `object.ReferenceEquals(statusBarSiteProduktiPoSIRTB, statusBarSiteSISoRokoviRTB)` if it says true you found your problem they should never be of same reference.

Comment: So what happens when you press the save button? And where is the code that you have posted located?